# Reflow temperatures vs chip removing temperature

Tags: reflow

Is "Reflow Temperature" the same as "Chip Removing Temperature"?

It says lead free solders melt at 250C. I tried to remove a chip at this temperature and heated it for 30 minutes but the solder did not melt and the chip stayed intact. Then I raised the temperature to 400C and the 480C. At this tempereature I was able to remove the chip (Intel Chipset.)

What is the right temperature?

During reflow with heatgun, should a chip's main die or the chip completely be heated and at what temperature?

In my experience I have successfully reflowed a Ci7 8550U CPU at 300C direct on two dies and at corners at 400C. Also an Intel H61 with direct 270C on die and 380C at corners (sides of the die not the die itself.) All successful operations.

I need to know is there difference between oven and heatgun temperatures.

Answer (score 1):

Heating a chip or die to 250 degrees does not mean that the solder will be at 250 degrees. Pushing heat to a chip means that the heat conducts away via solder joints to the PCB and the PCB can dissipate a lot of heat by conducting it away from the solder via copper planes. So it just takes a lot of heat to rise the temperature of the solder to a point where it melts. Pre-heating the PCB in an oven or on a thermal plate helps so not all the heat must come from the heat gun.

Comment: Thank you. Yes logical.

Answer (score 1):

Temperatures when using hot air are a bit tricky.  To start, you are not certain that your hot air station is calibrated properly, so it may say 250 but it may be off by any percentage.  Other things you have to factor in:

- Even if the air temperature is at 250, that is usually at the point of measurement, usually somewhere near the output nozzle, however, the distance at which you hold the nozzle away from the chip can drastically change the temperature that the chip "feels".
- The airflow matters; once the air it's out of the nozzle, it cools down due to the ambient temperature being much lower.  So higher airflow ensures there is less time for the air to cool down, but it may blow a chip or neighbouring parts away so there is a tradeoff.
- The design of the board matters a lot.  The recommended approach is to spend a bit of time blowing hot air over the entire board, or at least a wide area around the chip you are trying to remove (the soaking phase); however, if the board has thick copper planes, it can be really hard to warm a spot as the board acts as a heat sink pulling the heat away.  You can use a "hotbed" but that's hard to do if a board is built and contains through-hole parts.

There are probably other issues I'm forgetting but you can see, there is a lot going on.

Ovens are a bit simpler - since the entire board is enclosed, it gets uniformly heated and the rate of temperature increase is such to ensure that the entire board follows along, without cold/hot spots.  Most commercial ovens have decent temperature probes as well, so in general, they work better for a new board.  But of course, you can't use them to remove a chip.

If you need to use a heat gun, I would recommend you try some experiments on a test board before trying to remove the "important chip".  I get impatient so I put a timer, and I start with the wide nozzle 3-4 cm away, making wide circles around the part for about 30-40 seconds.  Then I move the nozzle closer and wait another 10-20 seconds while gently "probing" the part to see if it is coming loose.  If that doesn't work, I increase the temperature by 5 to 10 degrees and start again.  Over time, I have found the temperature for my station that works, yet I still run into boards that give me trouble, especially with higher copper thickness.

And as you mention, when dealing with larger chips, you can focus the airflow mostly on the perimeter as you are trying to heat the pins, not the die itself (unless of course, it has a solder pad underneath).

Comment: Thank you. As you said the whole object needs to be heated so more heat balances the theory.     .........    You wrote: And as you mention, when dealing with larger chips, you can focus the airflow mostly on the perimeter as you are trying to heat the pins, not the die itself (unless of course, it has a solder pad underneath). Is it for reflow or removing chip? I have reflown only the dies with 270C and the GPU worked. Also I have experience only heating the perimeter of Gpu not the die itself at 450C does the job. Event I have removed the DIE and seen the tiny sized ballings beneath it.

Comment: @MbB, I meant removing.  BTW, 450C sounds pretty hot, I would worry about damaging the chip, unless you keep the nozzle away so the temperature the chip experiences is lower.

Comment: PC motherboards cannot deal with Temps  >400C. But Laptops can handle. PC motherboards start to burn or the layers start to expand like a balloon :) But not all. Some Caps are soldered in a way seems like melting  aluminum not lead :)